# Independence between a Bernoulli random variable and a normal random variable

Tags: probability

Let

$$\varphi_{X,Y}(\theta_1,\theta_2)=e^{-i\theta_1}e^{-(\theta_1^2+4\theta_1\theta_2+5\theta_2^2)}$$

the characteristic function af a random vector.

If $Z\sim Bernoulli\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is independent from $X$, calculate the characteristic function of $(Z-1)(X-1)$.

I've found out that the vector is gaussian and $X$ is a normal random variable with expectation $-1$ and variance $2$.

Then, I tried to prove that $Z$ and $X$ are independent using the fact that, if they are, $f_{X,Z}(x,z)=f_X(x)f_Z(z)$ but I can't write the joint density.

So, I thought to conditionate by $Z$ (that assumes only 0 and 1) but, still, I can't develop  $P(X\leq x, Z=0)$ because I don't know the joint density.

I can't figure it out, any suggestions? And then, how can I write the characteristic function in case I have independence?

Comment: If the problem says $Z$ is independent from $X$ why are you trying to prove that $Z$ and $X$ are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, you don't need to (and cannot) prove that $Z$ and $X$ are independent. That is true by assumption.

If $A,B$ are independent, then so are $e^{i\theta_1 A}$ and $e^{i\theta_2 B}$, so the joint characteristic function is the product of the individuals. This is because $$\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta_1 A}e^{i\theta_2 B}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta_1 A}]\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta_2 B}]=\varphi_A(\theta_1)\varphi_B(\theta_2).$$

Last, for a constant $c$ and a r.v. $A$, $$\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta_1(A-c)}]=e^{-i\theta_1 c}\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta_1 A}]=e^{-i\theta_1 c}\varphi_A(\theta_1).$$ So translation of $A$ by a constant is equivalent to multiplying the characteristic function by a constant phase.

You could do this the long way by noting that, since $X$ and $Z$ are independent by assumption $\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant x,Z=0)=\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant x)\mathbb{P}(Z=0)$.